# $\sum_{i=0}^n {2n \choose 2i} = 2^{2n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n {2n \choose 2i} = 2^{2n-1} $$

I know what this sum is supposed to equal.  I also have a hint that I am supposed to use ${n \choose r} = {n-1 \choose r-1} + {n-1 \choose r}$

I was just wondering if someone could help me with where to start.

Do you start with:

$$ {2n-1 \choose 2i-1} + {2n-1 \choose 2i}$$ $$={(2n-1)! \over (2i-1)!(2n-1-(2i-1)!}+{(2n-1)! \over 2i!(2n-1-2i)!}$$

Comment: Something is wrong. You have $i<n$ for all bu the last term. So $\binom{2i}{2n}=0$ for all but the last term. The last term is $\binom{2n}{2n}$ which is just $1$. So the sum is just $1$.

Comment: My $i$ and $n$ are backwards.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: $$\sum_{i\text{ is odd}} {2n \choose i} = \sum_{i \text{ is even}}{ 2n\choose i}$$
and
$$
\sum_i {2n \choose i} = 2^{2n}
$$

Comment: Nice proof. Are you OK with my edit?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks. Look good to me.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}$$and$$0=(1-1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k.$$
Adding these gives you
$$2^n=2\left(\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}+\cdots\right),$$
i.e.
$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}+\cdots=2^{n-1}.$$

Now $n\to 2n$.

Answer (score 3):

Recommendation: use the Binomial Theorem on
$$ (1+x)^{2n} + (1-x)^{2n}, $$
then set $x=1$.

Comment: and divide by $2$

Comment: Well, yes, but I felt that part was fairly clear after one had worked out the binomial expansions...

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a small typo in the statement: perhaps you meant $$ \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{2n}{2i}=2^{2n-1}.$$

In order to prove this, you need to know that $$ \sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j\binom{m}{j}=0$$ and $$ \sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}{j}=2^m.$$  [This holds true because of the binomial theorem applied to $(1-1)^m=0$ and $(1+1)^m=2^m$, respectively. Alternatively you can look for some combinatorial interpretation.]

The first equation gives you $$S=\sum_{j\ \mathrm{even}} \binom{m}{j}= \sum_{j\ \mathrm{odd}} \binom{m}{j}$$

while the second equation gives you $2S=2^m$, i.e. $S=2^{m-1}$. Setting $m=2n$ yields what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The sum $\sum_{i=0}^n{2n\choose 2i}$ counts the sets in ${\cal P}:={\cal P}\bigl([2n]\bigr)$ having  an even number of elements. The map $\iota: \>A\mapsto A\triangle\{1\}$ (symmetric difference) is an involution of ${\cal P}$ interchanging the parity of the affected sets. It follows that the sum in question is $={1\over2}|{\cal P}|=2^{2n-1}$.